# Why does sorting of a list work outside of, but not within the print function in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list in Python which I want to sort by alphabet.
If I do this directly within the the `print()` function, it yields "None", while it works fine if I sort it first and then print it. Here is the reproducible code:

```
def main():
    l = ["Tina", "Alice"]
    print(l.sort())
    # yields "None"
    
    l.sort()
    print(l)
    # yields ["Alice", "Tina"]
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Can someone explain to me what the difference is in the background for Python? Some other operations like adding numbers etc. work fine within the `print()` function. Thanks!

Comment: `list.sort()` returns `None`, which is why it's printing `None`. However, it does sort the list, so if after `print(l.sort())` you were to put `print(l)`, you'd get the sorted list.

Comment: Please read the documentation for the function that is not doing what you expect, [sort](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) in this case, before posting a question to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks @MattDoMo! And you are right @jarmod, reading more may have also helped...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `sort` function returns None, it modifies the list itself.

There are `sorted` function too, which doesn't modify list but returns new one

```
print(sorted(l))
```

For more information look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)